# What is the proper terminology?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

I flip two coins; the possible combinations of H and T are (HH, HT, TH, TT). While I may describe each of these sequences as "combinations", what is the proper term for the body of all possible combinations? "Combination space", "configuration space, or perhaps something else?

Comment: Sample space? Also, what you are calling "combinations" would more typically be called "outcomes."

Comment: +1 to Bungo. If you look up [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) you will see it consists of 'sample space' and the set of events with assigned probabilities.

Comment: It could be also called an "elementary event" of the experiment "toss two coins". This terminology is often used in the important laplacian case.

Comment: Elementary event is very apt considering the message I am trying to convey.